# How can I maintain user engagement/interest during "off weeks" for a weekly podcast?

Tags: user-engagement, user-retention, promotion

I help run the social media for (and am a player in) a weekly *Dungeons & Dragons* 5th edition actual-play podcast set in a homebrew campaign setting of the Dungeon Master's own creation. We livestream episodes every Wednesday. However, from time to time, we have to take a week off, due to either the Dungeon Master or several players being unable to make it to the session.

**How can we maintain user engagement/interest during such "off weeks" for our weekly podcast?**

**Would the best ways to do this vary when the DM is absent vs. when some players are absent?** (For instance, Q&As about the campaign setting wouldn't work without the DM who made it.)

Please support answers by citing evidence or (more likely) experience, per [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/).